# SQL query issue in avoid duplicates in INSERT INTO SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following query works perfectly,

```
insert into [EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails] 
Select Distinct B.CountyB as 'Mobile' ,  Cast(BuildingB as Varchar(100)) as 'Email' , 
A.CardCode , A.CardName as 'First Name' , '' as 'Last Name' , 
'' as Gender , Cast(A.Address as Varchar(1000)) as 'Address' , Convert(Varchar(10), A.U_BirthDay,105) as 'birthday' , 
Convert(Varchar(10), A.U_AnnivDay ,105) as 'Anniversary' , 
Case 
When A.CardCode Like '%%'+ C.WhsCode +'%%'  Then Convert(Varchar(10) , A.DocDate ,105) 
Else Convert(Varchar(10), (Select X.CreateDate From OCRD X Where X.CardCode = A.CardCode) ,105) End as 'JoinDate' , 
C.WhsCode as 'JoinStore','Open' as Status ,(Select GETDATE()) as CreatedDateTime,(Select GETDATE()) as ProcessDateTime, '' as StatusMSg 
From OINV A 
Inner Join INV12 B On A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry 
Inner Join INV1 C On A.DocEntry = C.DocEntry 
Where C.LineNum = '0'

--B.CountyB not in(select D.Mobile from [EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails] D where D.Mobile=B.CountyB)
--not exists (select Mobile from [EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails] D where D.Mobile=B.CountyB)
```

But before I insert records into the `[EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails]` table, I need to check whether the phone number already exists in the table. If the record already exists, there is no need to insert it again. For that I have added one more condition (which I have commented out in the query) but it reports this error while running the query:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.
```

Comment: Please write your error code.

Comment: Error : Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3247327) you have to add `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` to the queries like this:

```
Where C.LineNum = '0' AND
B.CountyB not in(select D.Mobile from [EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails] D where D.Mobile COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = B.CountyB COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AND
not exists (select Mobile from [EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails] D where D.Mobile COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = B.CountyB COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: yes, Error i have faced "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" in the equal to operation."

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this before your query:

```
USE [db name for object INV12]
GO

ALTER TABLE [EGallery].dbo.[CustomerDetails]
  ALTER COLUMN Mobile
    VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE INV12
  ALTER COLUMN CountyB
    VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
```

UPDATE1:
If you have an index on one of this columns, or on both of them, you need to delete it and create index again after a new collation will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement, as it

> performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one table based on differences found in the other table.